# Duplicate values in a dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to read through a csv file in the following format:

```
number,alphabet
1,a
2,b
3,c
2,b
1,a
```

My code to create a dictionary:

```
alpha = open('alpha.csv','r')
csv_alpha = csv.reader(alpha)

alpha_file = {row[0]:row[1] for row in csv_alpha}
```

OUTPUT:

```
alpha_file = { 1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c' }
```

By looking at the file, 1 and 2 have duplicate values.

How can i possibly change my output to :

```
alpha_file = { 1:'a', 1:'a', 2:'b', 2:'b', 3:'c' }
```

LNG - PYTHON

Comment: short answer, you cant. dicts are made to have unique keys. long answer, you can connect each key to a list instead of a single integer

Comment: In a dictionary, keys must all be distinct. You can't have any duplicates in a dictionary. Why do you want to have duplicates?

Comment: @El'endiaStarman i need to find the occerrence of each key for a designated value. So if i have 2 a's i have two 1's. Right now i only get one 1. 
But it's true i need to find some other way to solve this problem. keys are immutable and cannot have duplicates

Comment: Why don't you just create a list of tuples?

Comment: You can use a dictionary where values are list

Comment: @TomaszKaminski I tried that but since i am dealing with huge files it take the program around 10-15 minutes to get the output. Programs work faster with dictionaries that's why.

Comment: @Luke If the order of values doesn't matter, you can create a dictionary of `set`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `list` to hold key's value

```
alpha = open('alpha.csv','r')
csv_alpha = csv.reader(alpha)

alpha_file = dict()
for row in csv_alpha:
    if row[0] in alpha_file:
        alpha_file[row[0]].append(row[1])
    else:
        alpha_file[row[0]] = [row[1]]
```

the output will be like:

```
{ 1:['a','a'],2:['b','b'], 3:['c'] }
```

to output the number of key occurrences, use a `for` loop

```
d = { 1:['a','a'],2:['b','b'], 3:['c'] }
amount = []
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    amount += [key] * len(value)
print amount
```

output looks like:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You could use a `defaultdict` to prevent having to check if the value already exists in the dict.